# The input data is not a complete block when trying to encrypt a key

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to encrypt some key and its throwin 
`The input data is not a complete block`. I tried some answers on stackoverflow but none of them seems to work!

here's the code:

```
public static string Encrypt(string value)
        {
            string EncryptionKey = "THISISSOMEENCRYPTIONKEY";
            byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                encryptor.BlockSize = 128;
                encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close(); //the input data is not a complete block
                    }
                    value = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
```

p.s. I have the same code on some of my old projects on `ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC` and its working properly, and this one is .NET Core 2.2 (Library) API and its throwing me that error!

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at following lines

```
Aes encryptor = Aes.Create()

encryptor.BlockSize = 128;
encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
```

AES cipher is a symmetric block cipher requiring that the input matches exactly the block size. If the input length doesn't match the block size, the input is extended to required length using [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) (usually PKCS#7 for symmetric cipher).

In the code `PaddingMode.None` is specified, so the input length must match the block size.

To encrypt longer input (multiplier of the block size), different [modes of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) are used. For your chosen parameters **the input lenght needs to be multiple of the block size** (16 bytes).

Please note some modes are effectively creating a stream ciphers and don't require paddings (CFB, OFB, CTR)

Let's try:

```
encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
```

> I have the same code on some of my old projects on ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC and its working properly

Well - then we can only assume the input length is multiple of the block size

Other security notes:

- avoid ECB if possible (see the link for modes of operation)
- other modes require unique IV (CBC mode requires unpredictable/random IV). Deriving (the same) key and IV for multiple inputs is really not safe